# Кабмин - с маленькой или с большой буквы?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Подскажите, пожалуйста, по поводу написания слова "кабмин" (Кабинет министров). В словаре зафиксировано написание: Кабинет министров - с большой. Логично писать сокращенный вариант тоже с большой (как Госдума - Государственная дума). Но если слово Госдума - это официальное сокращение, которое зафиксировано и в документах, и в словарях, то кабмина нигде нет, оно не зафиксировано. В СМИ везде встречаю с маленькой. Так как все же правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Если ориентироваться на "Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации"<sup>1</sup>:

> §208. С прописной буквы и слитно пишутся сложносокращенные слова, обозначающие названия учреждений и организаций, если соответствующее полное наименование пишется с прописной буквы.

Аналогично и у Розенталя<sup>2</sup>:

> §27.1. С прописной буквы пишутся сложносокращенные слова, обозначающие названия учреждений и организаций, в случае если словосочетание в полном виде пишется с прописной буквы.

Другое дело, что Кабинета Министров в России нет. Кабмин СССР был упразднен в 1991, сохраняются Кабмины на постсоветском пространстве, например в Республике Татарстан есть утвержденный конституцией Кабинет Министров.

Поэтому, если вы видите сокращение *кабмин* (с маленькой буквы), используемое в отношении Правительства Российской Федерации, то это не употребление сокращенного названия и не имя собственное, а имя нарицательное, употребляемое как описание органа, нежели его наименование.

---

1. Валгина Н. С., Еськова Н. А., Иванова О. Е., Кузьмина С. М., Лопатин В. В., Чельцова Л. К. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под редакцией В. В. Лопатина. — 2-е изд., испр. и доп. — М.: Эксмо, 2007.
2. Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П. Справочник по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию, М.: ЧеРо, 1999.